# Disable drop event on hidden droppable area

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I've implemented a web page and for the purpose of this question, it can be simplified to the picture below. Users are allowed to drag purple elements from the the blue side (drag zone) and drop them on the orange rectangles of the green side (drop zone).

[image]

The blue side takes a percentage of the page. The elements of each orange rectangle are listed horizontally. When a lot of elements get added to the orange drop zones, they expand to show all the dropped purple items. This expands the green side, but since the blue side always takes a certain percentage of the page, the green side's overflow can only be seen by horizontally scrolling it.

If orange rectangles have expanded long enough that the green side needs to be scrolled to see the items in the orange rectangles and a purple element is released within the blue area, the orange drop zones pick up the drop event. Even though the the item was dropped outside of what visually seems to be the drop zone, since droppable zones exists under the blue area, the drop event is picked up.

How can the orange rectangles be restricted to only fire up when they are not underneath the blue zone?